# How to specify width of literal character strings in a Python f-string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.6+, one can print integer literals in columns of a specified width with an f-string as in

```
print(f"{1:10}{2:10}{3:10}")
```

How can I do something similar with string literals?  i.e. Instead of printing 1, 2, and 3 in 10-character columns, how would I print "One", "Two", and "Three" in 10-character columns?

Can it be done using an f-string with a single line of code, or must I code it as follows?

```
a = "One"
b = "Two"
c = "Three"
print(f"{a:10}{b:10}{c:10}"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do a one-liner with strings using the following format:

```
print(f"{'One':>10}")
#        One
```

See the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). Note the relevant section:

> `>` Forces the field to be right-aligned within the available space **(this is the default for numbers)**.

(Emphasis added)

This is why you don't need the `>` when formatting numbers.